# php: DateTime() and time() have different time

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, vagrant, homestead

I'm using Vagrant box (Homestead) where the timezone is set to Europe/Brussels.

Current time that I get in terminal using command "date", returns this value:

> Sun Mar 25 23:27:40 CEST 2018

In both cli & fpm php.ini file I've:

> date.timezone = "Europe/Brussels"

Running following code simultaneously:
print_r(new DateTime());
print_r(time());

Gives these results:
For DateTime():

```
[
  "date" => "2018-03-25 23:27:43.650908",
  "timezone_type" => 3,
  "timezone" => "Europe/Brussels"
]
```

And the epoch timestamp for time()

```
1522013263
```

Converting the latter gives:

```
Sun, 25 Mar 2018 21:27:43 GMT
```

Given the results from DateTime I can assume that the timezone settings in php.ini are correct. But then why is the time between DateTime and time is different?

Answer (score 2):

[`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) returns the Unix timestamp and is always in GMT:

> Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the
>   Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

And `21:27:43 GMT` *is* equal to `23:27:43 CEST`.

As noted in the comments: Actually the unix timestamp is in UTC, but PHP [does not seem to make much of a difference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php). Unfortunately the documentation is not very enlightening in regards to this.

Comment: Strictly speaking the Unix clock is aligned with UTC not GMT, although the difference is small enought not to matter for most purposes.

Comment: So what should I use then to set the expiration time for a cookie? DateTime and convert it to the timestamp, or time()? It's really confusing.

Comment: If you are using [`setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) then this function expects a Unix timestamp as returned by `time()`.

Comment: @Marvin, I know that setcookie expects Unix timestamp. But getting timestamp using time() function gives me the wrong time. i.e. it gives the time -2 hours. So if I set cookies expiration time to 3600 the cookies will then be already expired for 2 hours. It means that I should get the user's browser timezone and set the cookie time accordingly?

Comment: It does _not_ give you the wrong time - just the same point in time _in a different time zone_. And [RFC 6265](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6265.txt) also expects GMT/UTC (cf. 5.1.1), [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) even requires it (cf. 3.3.1; explicitly stating that GMT and UTC are equal for the purposes of HTTP).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very experienced with PHP myself, but for time() I see GMT. Is GMT the Time zone you are using, or UTC (or something else)? They may be completely seperate.

[If i am incorrect, try reading here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp)

Or for more advanced information, [Try here.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)